# Verifying firebase custom token to get token ID fails when using jsonwebtoken

Tags: node.js, firebase, jwt, firebase-admin

On the backend a custom token is generated via firebase's admin SDK thusly:

```
router.use('/get-token', (req, res) => {
    var uid = "big-secret";
    admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
      .then(function(customToken) {
        res.json({
          instanceID: customToken
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
    });
});
```

The client frontend app then picks up the customToken and with it makes a request back to the backend to verify:

```
const fbPrivateKey = serviceAccount.private_key;
const key = new NodeRSA(fbPrivateKey).exportKey('pkcs8-public-pem');
router.get('/verifyIdToken', cors(), (req, res) => {
  jwt.verify(req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1], key, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }, function(err, decoded) {
    console.log('err', err);
    console.log('decoded', decoded);
  });
```

**This always errors with the message: `JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature`**

Does this need signing? If anyone could explain this or has any pointers?

**UPDATE:** 
When running `req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1]` through [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) is says that the signature is invalid, but then I enter my private key (`key`) and it validates.

Am I getting the method calls incorrect or passing the wrong arguments into `jwt.verify()` ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like you're calling `verifyIdToken` with a custom token. That's not going to work. `verifyIdToken` only accepts "ID tokens". To obtain an ID token from a custom token first call [`signInWithCustomToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth#authenticate-with-firebase). Then call [`getToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) on the signed in user instance.

Comment: Thanks so much :)

Comment: This answer is confusing, what you are talking about is admin.auth().verifyIdToken() which yes it can only verify ID tokens and not custom tokens. But in the post this is not used anywhere, the /verifyIdToken is just a route that Harry has configured for verifying ids. I think @Harry was just exporting the public-key wrong, check my answer below.

Answer (score 11):

If you dont want to use signInWithCustomToken() this is the correct way to do it

```
const publicKey = new NodeRSA().importKey(serviceAccount.private_key, "pkcs8-private-pem").exportKey("pkcs8-public-pem")

jwt.verify(token, publicKey, {
        algorithms: ["RS256"]
    }, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            # send some error response
            res.status(400).json({
                status: 0,
                message: "Token is invalid!"
            })
        } else {
            # send some valid response
            res.status(200).json({
                status: 1,
                message: "Token is valid for uid " + decoded.uid
            })
        }
    })
```

Comment: You might not need the public key. With the jsonwebtoken package (repo: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) you can just send the serviceAccount.private_key as second argument, so there wouldn't be need for NodeRSA.

Comment: @DanielReina, I'm not sure that's correct. The documentation says that `jwt.verify` requires a secret or public key. In this case, the PEM encoded public key. And I just tried this with the private key and it returned an error saying the algorithm was invalid