# Firebase Rest API for Token creation/verification does not have any result

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

We use Firebase for Authenticating our login process, at the backend we have a Rest API implementation in order to verify the token that is being passed.

I have modified the .json file and verified yet another time too in my code base. I have extracted the entire process of generating the token from the UID and this is how this looks:

```
public void initialization(){
        try {
            FileInputStream refreshToken = new FileInputStream("c02955c26b.json");

            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(refreshToken))
                    .setDatabaseUrl("https://164d0.firebaseio.com")
                    .build();
            String uid = "Lp14BXL3xPVW7K8VZX28omynbWx1";
            FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance(FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options));
            System.out.println(" "+firebaseAuth); --> I see this on the console 
            String customToken = firebaseAuth.createCustomToken(uid);
            System.out.println(" "+customToken); 

            FirebaseToken decodedToken = firebaseAuth.verifyIdToken(customToken);
            String uidTranspose = decodedToken.getUid();
            System.out.println(" the UID sent is"+uid+"Obtained after transpose is"+uidTranspose);
            System.out.println(" the UID captured is this "+uid);

        }
        catch(Error e){
            System.out.println(" "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            System.out.println("Finally comes here ");
        }
    }
```

Somewhere on hitting the token creation, the control flows directly to the finally block; without logging an error or an exception.

I am not sure if I am missing anything here.

Edit 1: Edited to add the complete code.

Edit 2: I am able to see the Token being created. but I am unable to verify the same; because it says this is a custom token and not the Id Token. I am not sure if I can access the Id Token or if there is a way to verify the custom token.

Comment: I don't see any try/catch/finally in your code.  Could you edit your question to post the complete, minimal example that doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @DougStevenson I have done that

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `verifyIdToken()` with a custom token. See [Verifying firebase custom token to get token ID fails when using jsonwebtoken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368643/verifying-firebase-custom-token-to-get-token-id-fails-when-using-jsonwebtoken)